# Is porting QML based app easy to Windows Phone?

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

On the qt-project web-site there're available sources as for porting QML to iOS, Android.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/portingtoandroid.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/porting-to-ios.html

It appears to be easy.

Is it so for Windows Phone as well?

Is it so for any other platform?

Answer (score 0):

Qt Project has a [Qt for WinRT tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/winrt-support.html) providing a step-by-step process to build applications for Windows 8 based devices. Basically to resume the tutorial :

- You need the appropriate windows runtime
- You may have to build Qt from source for that runtime library
- You develop and compile Qt as you would do for a desktop app
- You have an additional step for packaging the application.